# Certain faces seems to stretch texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, normals, texture-coordinates

I'm coding up a simple mesh and using a fixed JPG square as texture.
On most faces it looks OK, but on the middle-top of the mesh, it seems the texture gets stretched for some reason.

It's a single mesh, the entire model uses the same texture repeated on the faces. Is there some kind of setting for the face I can make? I already checked the face's normal, which seemed fine (picture added).

I'm fairly new to Blender, so it's most likely a simple setting for the face I'm messing up.

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: Hi! How do you apply the texture. Do you use UV mapping or something else?

Comment: as mugnozzo suggests, you need to show us how you've unwrapped the object, for example make a screenshot of the UV Editor

Comment: The UV Mapping editor was not even used for this one; I am happy to apply the image repeating to the faces, so it's created through a simple Material with a texture loaded in, assigned to the faces.

Though what you say makes sense; unwrapping it and manually dragging the mapping fixes it... I am curious to find out why the simple assign works on some faces, but not on others (in this case only 10% of the faces in the mesh)

Comment: Assume the situation resolved though; I can't figure out why a direct Material apply fails in a few cases, but manual UV mapping fixes it.